# design and login in a SQL query

Tags: sql-server

I have a new project and just need some advice on how to do it efficiently and fast.

I have a  table with about 100,000 rows with about 50 to 60 fields. It is indexed and has a primary key. The primay key in this case is a barcode.

I have to create a query that goes through each row and check for rules at each step.

For example the first rule is checking if digit 3 of the primary  key is 0. So code wise it would be `SUBSTRING(PkgBarcode, 3, 1) = 0`

If this rule fails, I'd like to print out a message. 
Also regardless if this rule fails or passes, I'd like to continue on because the rules are not dependent on each other, ie it might fail rule 2 but pass rule 3 which is okay.

I am seeking best design practices. Would it be efficient to just use select statements with  print messages or some sort of loop? 
How would you do this fast and efficiently?

Comment: [Stack Overflow is not your personal research assistant](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128553/140505)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to do this "through each row" but rather with standard set theory.  For example, you could add a BIT column for each test you need to run, and then run a query to update that bit based on the test:

```
UPDATE tblMyTable
SET [IsThirdDigitZero] = 0
WHERE SUBSTRING(PkgBarcode, 3, 1) <> 0
```

That makes it easy to pull a list of the ones that do not meet a certain test while avoiding a cursor.

Comment: Thankyou, that sounds like a good way to do it. However to begin this script I have. `SELECT * INTO #TempTable FROM master_table`. Should I manually add the bit columns in or create a new table with the bit columns

Comment: Yes, you can do the 'SELECT * INTO' first and then 'ALTER TABLE #TempTable ADD [IsThirdDigitZero] BIT NULL', then I'd probably 'UPDATE #TempTable SET [IsThirdDigitZero] = 1' to set everything to 1 (rather than NULL), followed by your update to set the appropriate values to zero.  Of course, you'll need to do that for each test you want to run, and then you'll need to do something with the results before the temp table is destroyed.  Am I making sense?